# javascript open save as dialog box and store content

Tags: javascript

in javascript (in browser, not node), i would like to open the browser save as dialog box, then get the full path for the file and use it to save a file.

the code below is what i have, but i am unable to find how to show the save as dialog box. i've tried my luck with things like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle/entries but did not succeed.

```js
document.getElementById('downloadButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Generate the content you want to download as a string
  const content = 'This is the content of the downloadable file.';

  // Create a Blob (Binary Large Object) from the content
  const blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });

  // Create a link element for downloading the file
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = 'downloaded-file.txt'; // Specify the default filename

  // Trigger a click event on the link to initiate the download
  a.click();

  // Clean up resources (revoke the URL to free up memory)
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

how can i open the save as dialog box and use the returned filename to save the a content (not only in chrome)?

**update:**
i found [an example for Storage Manager on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/getDirectory), but i am unable to make it work. i get an error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.

and it happens on the line of

```js
const draftHandle = await root.getFileHandle("draft.txt", { create: true });
```

Comment: Other than the fact that `url` doesn't exist, your code should work.

Comment: @FZs it works but it does not open the save as dialog box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i open the save as dialog box and use the returned filename to save the a content (not only in chrome)?

As far as I know, the best solution would be to use [`window.showSaveFilePicker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker) which is only supported in Chrome/chromium based browsers.

Your code will work in most browsers, but depending on how the user's browser is configured, a save as dialog box may or may not show up.

In Firefox, enabling this setting will cause a save as dialog box to show up when your code is run
[image: firefox setting]

Comment: thank you. if you look at my post update, could you tell when it does not work?

Comment: @Mr. The storage manager example works for me, but StorageManager isn't supposed to be used for saving files to a user's (OS) filesystem. It's used for accessing the origin private filesystem.